# How to install Glassfish Server on Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Could someone explain me how to add Glassfish Server to Netbeans? After clicking on next I get some error.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1770/gioew/index.html your answer? And https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1770/gimvn/index.html as update.

Comment: My problem is I cannot select  GlassFish v3. There is always some error as depicted above.

Comment: Maybe the installation of your current copy of Netbeans is corrupt. Can you try to install another clean instance of Netbeans?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you mean I have to reinstall Netbeans?

Comment: Not yet. Install a second Netbeans in a different folder.

Comment: Now everything works after installing Netbeans 12.1. Thanks a lot!